# How to change title in differents tcolorbox using same style

Tags: tcolorbox, frame-title

I am trying to create a style class to display a box with a dynamic title using the `tcolorbox` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    .exercise_box/.style={
        skin=widget,
        boxrule=1mm,
        coltitle=black,
        colframe=blue!45!white,
        colback=blue!15!white,
        title={Non Mutually Exclusive Events}
    }
}

\newtcolorbox{exercise_box}{.exercise_box}

\begin{document}

    \begin{exercise_box}[title={example 4}]
        If A and B are two events that are not mutually exclusive then:  
        \tcblower
        $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$
    \end{exercise_box}

    \begin{exercise_box}[title={example 4.5}]
        If A and B are two events that are not mutually exclusive then:  
        \tcblower
        $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$
    \end{exercise_box}

    \begin{exercise_box}[title={example 5}]
        If A and B are two events that are not mutually exclusive then:  
        \tcblower
        $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$
    \end{exercise_box}

\end{document}
```

and get the following results

[image]
[image]

but the title of the boxes is not modified in any way and always shown the default title 'Non Mutually Exclusive Events'.

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}


\newtcolorbox{exercise_box}[1][Non Mutually Exclusive Events]{ 
    skin=widget,
    boxrule=1mm,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=blue!45!white,
    colback=blue!15!white,
    title=#1}

\begin{document}

    \begin{exercise_box}[example 4]
        If A and B are two events that are not mutually exclusive then:  
        \tcblower
        $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$
    \end{exercise_box}

    \begin{exercise_box}[example 4.5]
        If A and B are two events that are not mutually exclusive then:  
        \tcblower
        $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$
    \end{exercise_box}

    \begin{exercise_box}
        If A and B are two events that are not mutually exclusive then:  
        \tcblower
        $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$
    \end{exercise_box}

\end{document}
```

The "Non mutually..." is the default title, shows up if you don't specify a custom title. To specify a custom title just fill the optional argument.

[image]

Comment: @EdgarAlfonso you're welcome : )